# How can I display form in django admin depending on user, Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-admin

I want to display one form for superuser and another one for others stuff users. 
For example, the only superuser can fill/edit fields like author, likes_count, views_count...

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize corresponding `ModelAdmin` for your model.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import SuperuserForm, OtherForm


class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser():
            kwargs['form'] = SuperUserForm
        else:
            kwargs['form'] = OtherUserForm

        return super(MyAdmin, self).get_form(request,obj=obj,**kwargs)
```